# Dell T430 not seeing new drive

Tags: dell-poweredge, dell-perc

We have a new Dell power edge T430 with a 1TB SATA HD, and we are trying to add a second 1TB HD.

However, the drive does not seem to be recognised by any part of the system.

On booting, if I hit ^R to get into the PERC controller (H330, i think), only our original HD is shown, not the new one.

The only exception to this is the green light on the HD carrier is flashing, and if I remove the new HD, the status LCD on the front says that Disc 1 has been removed.

Is there some other option I need to play around with, or is it likely that the HD is faulty or incompatible with the Del server?

Comment: If it don't appear in the CLU at boot I fear your drive is not recognized at all, updated the raid controller firmware ?

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar issues with the H700 PERC Controllers in the past, I updated the Firmware and was then able to detect NON DELL disks.

You should be able to get the latest firmware from the Dell support site.

Comment: It's only about a month old, so the firmware should be good, but i'll check.

Comment: I have quite often had products from Dell new, But still found various driver, firmware updates since release. So defiantly worth a check.